# how do I know what files are installed by an installer program?

Tags: macos

How can I find out what files are installed by an installer program?  Is there a program that can trace that during an installation of a new app?

Answer (score 22):

You can press command-I in an installer window to see a list of files that would be copied by the installer:

[image]

You can also use `lsbom`:

```
lsbom bundle.pkg/Contents/Archive.bom
lsbom $(pkgutil --bom nonbundle.pkg)
```

If you have already installed a package, you can use `pkgutil --files` or `lsbom`:

```
pkgutil --files com.tapbots.TweetbotMac
lsbom /var/db/receipts/com.tapbots.TweetbotMac.bom
```

Comment: If the package is already installed, using `lsbom` or `pkgutil --files` doesn't actually tell you where the installed files are.  The full directory structure is listed out but you're not shown where on the system those files where installed.  (or if they still exist)

To find that, just run `pkgutil --pkg-info <pkg_id>` and you'll see the volume and install location.

Answer (score 2):

There’s an app called [**Pacifist**](http://www.charlessoft.com) (shareware, $20) which allows you to inspect OS X package files and look at their contents. Quoting directly from their website:

> This is useful, for instance, […] if you want to inspect a downloaded package to see what it will install before installing it.

You can download it for free (which has a 15 second delay on startup), or $20 to register. By using the **Open Package** command on an installer, you can look inside the installer package and find out what it’s doing. Usually you can find a script or similar, which you can use to see what gets installed and moved.

Comment: Or, if one is not willing to use for-pay software [unpkg](http://www.timdoug.com/unpkg/) is the tool of choice for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Within the **Installer.app** application, you can use the **File** > **Show Files…** menu to list the package contents. This list reflects the compressed files that Installer will copy onto your Mac.

**Installer.app** is launched when you open a standard installer package.

Be aware that an installer package, `pkg` and `mpkg`, can install files using scripts or other methods that are difficult to detect.

To truly determine what files are installed or modified, you would need to track and monitor the installer package as it was being applied to your Mac. This includes tracking processes launched by the installer and the results of any scripts it runs.

If you are uncertain about an installer, contact the developer. We for example [publish a list of files](http://dssw.co.uk/powermanager/guide/v4/administrator/admin.i.packing-reference.html) installed and any scripts used. It is good practice and customer demand will help push developers to share this detail.

Answer (score 1):

[@Lri](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/3936/)'s [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/125233/656) is excellent and I want to add info about another flag for `pkgutil`. From the manpage:

> `--payload-files path`
>
> List the files archived within the payload of the uninstalled flat package(s) contained at path.  This should be equivalent to `` "lsbom -s `pkgutil --bom path`" ``. Note that flat package archives may contain more than one package, and the destination location for the uninstalled package(s) is unknown to this command.

Example:

```sh
pkgutil --payload-files node-v10.15.3.pkg
```

Using this flag, I was able to see the same list as presented by the "Show Files" command (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>) in *Installer*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 10.4.x "Tiger" or 10.5.x "Leopard" then fslogger is one way to log changes to your system. This and other options are discussed here:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20091223115101622

Comment: Hmmmm... Interesting.... A solution for an OS from at least 2005 to a question asked in 2015.