# How can I monitor an installer as it modifies the filesystem on Yosemite?

Tags: filesystem, monitoring

[fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3Afseventer%3Astart) does not support Yosemite until further notice and the [suggestions here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/how-do-i-know-what-files-are-installed-by-an-installer-program) don't work for me so how can I monitor an installer as it writes files to the file system? I also tried [Sloth](http://sveinbjorn.org/sloth) but it only shows currently open files at a specific point in time.

Comment: In Super User: http://superuser.com/a/997722/84988 under [View Filesystem Access in Real Time on Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/q/97980/84988)

Answer (score 1):

This not application specific (it will show all) but you can find the one you are looking for.

iosnoop

This “traces” disk I/O execution live. Each time a disk I/O completes, a line of output is printed to summarize it, including process name and filename details:

Example:

```
sudo iosnoop

UID   PID D    BLOCK   SIZE       COMM PATHNAME

  503 54079 R 286522800   4096 Google Chrome ??/Cache/data_2
```

Answer (score 0):

### Derman Enterprises [File Control](http://www.derman.com/FileControl)

> … makes it easy to determine what's been changed anywhere on your system. …

On OS X 10.11.1, attempts to analyse

```
/opt
```

– during an installation by MacPorts – result in a 'No Items Were Processed' dialogue in File Control. So I assume that El Capitan is incompatible with such applications …

… but File Control *might* work with Yosemite. If not, please vote down this answer.

(I have El Capitan for test purposes, and I can run Mavericks later, but no Yosemite test environment.)